# Loading RecyclerView very slow

Tags: android, performance, android-volley, android-recyclerview

I am having an issue with the performance of my app, I can get the data to load in the view just fine, however, it is taking well over two minutes to produce the list. Is this down to my code is poorly optimized?

Below is my activity that I am calling the `RecyclerView` on.

```
public class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rlist;

    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration;
    private List<Riders> ridersList;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    public static Intent makeIntent(Context context) {
        return new Intent(context, ResultsActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

        rlist = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        ridersList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new RidersAdapter(getApplicationContext(),ridersList);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(rlist.getContext(),linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());

        rlist.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rlist.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        rlist.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        rlist.setAdapter(adapter);

        getData();
    }

    private void getData(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading results...");
        progressDialog.show();

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        Riders riders = new Riders();
                        riders.setName(jsonObject.getString("Full_Name"));
                        riders.setClub(jsonObject.getString("Club"));
                        riders.setFinishPosition(jsonObject.getString("Finish_Position"));

                        ridersList.add(riders);
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

The Json is loading in this format

```
"[{"Full_Name":"Sam sam",
"Club":"Club",
"Finish_Position":"1"
},
{  
"Full_Name":"Chris Chris",
"Club":"Club",
"Finish_Position":"2"
}"
```

It is all just one big string no break lines or anything? Any help would be greatly appciated.

Adapter is -

```html
public class RidersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RidersAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Riders> ridersList;
    private Context context;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, position, club;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_title);
            club = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_rating);
            position = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_year);
        }
    }


    public RidersAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<Riders> ridersList) {
        this.ridersList = ridersList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.singleitem, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Riders riders = ridersList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(riders.getName());
        holder.club.setText(riders.getClub());
        holder.position.setText(riders.getFinishPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ridersList.size();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the proper answer to your question. However, I was wondering how your `RecyclerView` is updated on getting response from server? I do not see any `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

You need to change the `onResponse` function like the following.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

            Riders riders = new Riders();
            riders.setName(jsonObject.getString("Full_Name"));
            riders.setClub(jsonObject.getString("Club"));
            riders.setFinishPosition(jsonObject.getString("Finish_Position"));

            ridersList.add(riders);
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        // You need to call notifyDataSetChanged to see the effect in your RecyclerView.
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
}
```